# Ext js paging with local data does not work

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, pagingtoolbar

I try to enable paging with ExtJs4 grid. Paging toolbar looks like it is working but paging is not enabled in grid.Can you help me about what I am missing?

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
        var i = 1;

    Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
             { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
             { name: 'firstName', type: 'string' },
             { name: 'lastName', type: 'string' },
             { name: 'age', type: 'int' },
             { name: 'eyeColor', type: 'string' }
        ]
    });
```

It looks that the problem is with totalCount but, there is something more.

```
  var store=  Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      model: 'User',
      totalCount:50,
      pageSize: 10,
      autoLoad: { start: 0, limit: 10 },

      proxy: {
          type: 'memory',
          reader: {
              root: 'users',
              totalProperty: 'totalCount'
          }

      },

  data: [
         { id: i++, firstName: 'Ed',    lastName: 'Spencer', age:20,  eyeColor: 'blue' },
         { id: i++, firstName: 'Tommy', lastName: 'Maintz',  age: 30, eyeColor: 'black' },
         { id: i++, firstName: 'Aaron', lastName: 'Conran',  age: 40, eyeColor: 'blue' },
         { id: i++, firstName: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Avins',   age: 50, eyeColor: 'black' },
         { id: i++, firstName: 'Ed',    lastName: 'Spencer', age: 20, eyeColor: 'blue' }

                                                 .
                                                 .
                                                 .

        ]
    });
```

Paging toolbar looks like it is working but grid values does not change according to the page numbers.

```
     Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Users',
        store: store,
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            enablePaging: true
        },
        columns: [
              { header: 'ID', dataIndex: 'id', width:50 },
            { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'firstName' },
            { header: 'Last Name', dataIndex: 'lastName' },
            { header: 'Age', dataIndex: 'age', width: 50 },
            { header: 'Eye Color', dataIndex: 'eyeColor' }

        ],
        height: 600,
        width: 800,
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store: store,
            pageSize: 10,
            dock: 'bottom',
            displayInfo: true
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `proxy: 'pagingmemory'` which is [Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy).

From [doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging):

> ### Paging with Local Data
>
> Paging can also be accomplished with local data using extensions:
>
> - Ext.ux.data.PagingStore
> - Paging Memory Proxy (examples/ux/PagingMemoryProxy.js)

Also note that there is no need to have:

- `totalCount` in the store config (it will be provided by the proxy);
- `proxy` on the grid (it's already within the store);
- `pageSize` in the paging toolbar config (will be taken from the store).